Unable to access one device from another on the same network
I have three devices on the same wireless network: a laptop, a desktop, and a phone.
I run a simple HTTP server on my laptop and my desktop.
When I access the server running on my desktop from either my laptop or my phone, it works fine.
When I access the server running on my laptop:

From my desktop, it works fine.
From my phone, I get ERR_ADDRESS_UNAVAILABLE.

Access from the phone to the laptop worked just fine until mid-afternoon today, when it suddenly stopped working. The only change I had made was to increase the inode watch limit on the laptop (which should be completely unrelated).
Why does just this one combination -- accessing the service on my laptop from my phone -- not work, and what can I do to fix it?
(I have already tried things like using incognito mode, restarting the phone, assigning a new IP address, and restarting my router. Nothing had any effect. There is no firewall on the laptop or any other device.)
The laptop runs Ubuntu 24.04, the desktop runs Fedora 41. The phone is a Samsung Galaxy running Android.

Does your Wi-Fi router/access point have a "Client isolation" setting anywhere?

Not as far as I can tell, and certainly nothing we have activated.

Hmm, it might be a ARP failure due to a multicast/broadcast failure. Does the laptop have a valid ARP table entry for the Android device? If not, does setting one manually fix the problem? Do you have a way to at least view, and preferably also edit, the ARP table on the Android device (I'm not an Android guy so I can't help you with that)? Do you have original WPA (TKIP) enabled, even optionally, on your AP (wireless router)? If so, disable it, because it makes multicast/broadcast more likely to fail. Use WPA2-only (AES-CCMP only) or WPA2/WPA3, but don't leave original WPA/TKIP available.

Thanks! The router only has WPA2/WPA3 enabled, not the original WPA.
So I guess the best lead is with the ARP table. Would rebooting the laptop clear that?

Circling back to this, I tried rebooting my laptop, phone, and router simultaneously (rebooting them individually didn't help). That did the trick.
My guess is that there was some corrupt state in the network stack of some combination of devices which went away when all affected devices were rebooted.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
